# JRELoadError when trying to open the jEdit text editor in MAC OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, jedit

I am getting JRELoadError when trying to open the jEdit application

But, I am able to open the application using the command from terminal:

```
java -jar /Applications/jEdit.app/Contents/java/jedit.jar
```

jEdit website [FAQ page](http://www.jedit.org/FAQ/problems.html#d0e1636) suggests to look at the jedit shell script provided by the installation routine to confirm that the script's commands target the correct files and locations. How do I know the location of the shell script file.

I installed the jEdit using homebrew command `brew cask install jedit`

Comment: http://community.jedit.org/?q=node/view/37943

Comment: I did not find a solution so for now I added an alias to jedit.jar and added this alias to the mac OS dock:- 
Go to `/Applications` folder. Right click on `jEdit.app` and select `Show Package Contents` and go to the path `/Applications/jEdit.app/Contents/Java/jedit.jar` and right click the jedit.jar -> Make Alias. Now select the alias icon and click `Control+Shift+Command+T` to add this as a icon on dock. You can customize the icon in the dock to look like jEdit icon if required

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okN0gC0_XOg

Answer (score 1):

firstpostcommenter's solution above works great for me. If you want to add a jEdit icon as suggested, here are the steps.

*Before* creating the alias as described above (if you already have, just do it again after this), do the following:

- In the same application package locate the file jEdit.app/Resources/icon.icns and double click it to open it.
- Pick one of the icons (I chose a lower-res version, the 3rd one down), right click on it, and select "export". Save it as a jEdit.png somewhere.
- Open up the jEdit.png file in Preview and copy it (Cmd-C).
- Right-click on the jEdit.app/Java/jedit.jar file and select "Get Info".
- Click the icon in the upper-left corner of the info window - it will highlight.
- Press Cmd-V to paste the icon onto the jEdit.jar file.
- Now create the alias, and the alias will have the jEdit icon on it.
- Drag the alias to the /Applications folder and rename it "jEditLauncher" (or whatever you like).
- Press Control+Shift+Command+T to add the icon to the dock, or just drag it there.

Hope that is helpful.